# How can I connect iMac as external monitor?

Tags: imac

How can I connect my iMac (Retina 4K, 21.5", 2019) version 12.3 to my MacBook Air(Retina, 13",2019) version 12.3? I have a Thunderbolt 3.

Comment: Share the screen or air display?

Comment: Apple **used** to have a feature like that: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204592

Answer (score 1):

You need additional hardware for this, such as the [Luna display](https://astropad.com/product/lunadisplay/).